# How do I remove extraneous packages with npm?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

If I run `npm ls` at the top level of my project, I get a number of extraneous errors. I tried running `npm prune` but when I run `npm ls` again the packages are still there.

How do I remove those extraneous packages?

I have package-lock file and I'm running npm 6.4.1.

Comment: **Just a note for others arriving from search engines**: *`npm prune`* is the command you're looking for and it should remove extra packages (and did in my case).

Answer (score 1):

First, did you do a `npm i` to be sure to install all the packages? You can also delete your `node_modules` folder and your `package-lock.json` file to have a clean install.

Then if you want to remove packages, you need to `npm uninstall` them or manually remove them from your `package.json` file, then re-do a `npm i`.

Comment: I did run npm install initially. I also deleted the node_modules directory but not the package-lock.json file. Wouldn't prune update packages.json and package-lock.json?

Comment: @ventsyv so does it work if you manually delete `package-lock.json` and manually remove the unwanted modules from `package.json` ? I'm not quite sure about `npm prune`

Comment: That did it but now when I run `npm ls` a get a large number of missing packets and 102 vulnerabilities?

Comment: can you post your package.json?